# Making a column case sensitive in sql

Tags: mariadb

I have created a database but now i wanted to make a column case sensitive for search purposes.

ALTER TABLE hospital_details ALTER COLUMN list COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;

this is the error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Review MariaDB's syntax of ALTER TABLE here:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/
You can use `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN` only to set a default or drop a default from a column.

If you want to change the column's collation, it's `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN` but you will have to specify the whole column definition including type, default, and collation.

Also be sure that the version of MariaDB you use supports the collation you named. Use `SHOW COLLATION` to view the collations available. Read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-collation/ for details.

I don't think MySQL or MariaDB support a collation named Latin1_General_CS_AS. What reference did you get that collation name from?

MariaDB does support a collation Latin1_General_CS.